# Why is the constructor in this C++ code ambiguous and how do I fix it?

Tags: c++, templates, implicit-conversion, explicit-constructor

In the below code, the compiler can't figure out which constructor I want to use. Why, and how do I fix this? ([Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/77f21f7dd5c964b3))

```
#include <tuple>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

template<typename data_type, typename eval_type, typename Type1, typename Type2>
class A
{
public:
    using a_type = std::tuple<Type1, Type2>;
    using b_type = std::tuple<std::size_t,std::size_t>;

    inline explicit constexpr A(const std::function<data_type(a_type)>& Initializer,
        const std::function<eval_type(data_type)>& Evaluator,
        const Type1& elem1, const Type2& elem2)
    {
        std::cout << "idx_type" << std::endl;
    }
    inline explicit constexpr A(const std::function<data_type(b_type)>& Initializer,
        const std::function<eval_type(data_type)>& Evaluator,
        const Type1& elem1, const Type2& elem2)
    {
        std::cout << "point_type" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    int a = 1;
    long long b = 2;
    auto c = A<double, double, long long, int>{
        [](std::tuple<long long,int> p)->double { return 1.0*std::get<0>(p) / std::get<1>(p); },
        [](double d)->double { return d; }, b,a
        };

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the live MCVE!

Comment: lambda are not `std::function`.

Comment: I had to reread the constructor parameters 3 times before I noticed `a_type` and `b_type` are different.

Comment: Short answer is that both constructors can be used because [the fifth](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/function) overload of `std::function`.

Comment: A [mcve] will actually look more like [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d03fb0862739eec4)

Comment: @SombreroChicken: And that `std::tuple<long long,int>` and `std::tuple<std::sizt_t,int>` are constructible from each other.

Comment: Which constructor do you want to use?

Comment: I would like to use the one with `b_type`

Comment: @Jarod42 Good addition, thanks.

Comment: @SobreroChicken, but i thought the using the keyword `explicit` should prevent the conversion from `std::tuple<long long,int>` to `std::tuple<long long,int>`

Comment: Another workaround alternative is to not use a tuple for the b_type, but instead roll your own.  `using b_type = struct { std::size_t a; std::size_t b; };`

Comment: thanks Eljay, however I want to keep the structure considering how all these elements fit together. Also, I give a particular example with 2 types, but my original class uses a variadic list of types. At that point, the struct solution is far less workable and requires doubling the code (one for use with a_type and one with b_type)

Comment: @AOK "... _should prevent the conversion from `std::tuple<long long,int>` to `std::tuple<long long,int>`_" It does if you change that converting constructor to a one argument constructor callable only by direct initialization, by marking it `explicit`, or if you remove that implicit conversion operator, whichever it is that perform the conversion (I haven't checked and don't want to, as it's irrelevant for the point I'm making). But then of course `std::tuple` is not a customization point, you can't change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @SombreroChicken mentioned, `std::function<R(Args...)>` has a constructor that allows *any* callable object `c` to initialize it, as long as `c(Args...)` is valid and returns something convertible to `R`.

To fix it, you may use some SFINAE machinery

```
#include <tuple>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename data_type, typename Type1, typename Type2>
class A
{
    template<typename T>
    struct tag
    {
        operator T();
    };

public:
    using a_type = std::tuple<Type1, Type2>;
    using b_type = std::tuple<std::size_t,std::size_t>;

    template<typename C, std::enable_if_t<std::is_invocable_v<C, tag<b_type>>>* = nullptr>
    A(C&& initializer)
    {
        std::cout << "size_t" << std::endl;
    }

    template<typename C, std::enable_if_t<std::is_invocable_v<C, tag<a_type>>>* = nullptr>
    A(C&& initializer)
    {
        std::cout << "other" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    auto c = A<double, long long, int>{
        [](std::tuple<long long, int> p) -> double { return 1; }
    };

    auto c2 = A<double, long long, int>{
        [](std::tuple<std::size_t, std::size_t>) -> double { return 2; }  
    };
}
```

[Live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7931097ecbb0bbe5)

Here, we turn off the constructor if the callable can be called with `b_type` or `a_type` respectively. The extra indirection through `tag` is there to disable the conversion between tuples of different types

Comment: I've been trying to put this together for VC++, but `std::is_invocable_v` isn't available and I can't get `std::_Is_invocable_r` to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: @AOK It seems like MSVC doesn't have this yet. You may try implement it yourself. A possible implementation is to first implement [`invoke`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke) and SFINAE on whether the invocation is successful

Comment: I tried to take a stab at it from a different angle (mostly since I had the structures for it already built), but it doesn't seem to be working. I posted it up as another questions because I feel it might be sufficiently different, in case you want to take a peek: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49286989/how-to-properly-use-stdenable-if-in-c-on-a-constructor)

Answer (score 4):

The reason it doesn't work is because a lambda is not a `std::function` and so the compiler tries to create one using [the fifth](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/function) overload of the constructor. The problem is that both of your `A` constructors can be used because of this conversion and the reason that `std::tuple<long long,int>` and `std::tuple<std::size_t,std::size_t>` are constructible from each other makes this ambigious for the compiler what constructor to pick.

What you could do is explicitly cast to the desired `std::function` (MCVE of @PasserBy used in comments), [like this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/abe43f9a5961c15e):

```
#include <tuple>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

template<typename data_type, typename Type1, typename Type2>
class A
{
public:
    using a_type = std::tuple<Type1, Type2>;
    using b_type = std::tuple<std::size_t,std::size_t>;

    A(const std::function<data_type(a_type)>&)
    {
        std::cout << "idx_type" << std::endl;
    }
    A(const std::function<data_type(b_type)>&)
    {
        std::cout << "point_type" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::function<double(std::tuple<long long, int>)> func = [](auto p) -> double { return 1; };
    auto c = A<double, long long, int>{
        func
    };
}
```

Comment: I was hoping for some solution that mucks around with `class A`, but this will have to do for now. Thanks!